# Fiction Romance. Heroine uses her psychic ability such as telepathy and psychometry to help find a man who's been kidnapped

Tags: story-identification, novel, telepathy, psychic, ebooks

This was an ebook I downloaded before, and read around the late 90s but it could be around the late 80s, and I think it's a standalone too. It's about a woman around her early or possibly late 20s with psychic ability wherein by just touching something that belongs to a person, she will be able to know where that person is, and I think she can see bits of the past of what happened or the general gist of it through the depth of emotional attachment. She kind of works with the authorities, although not directly. With this ability she was able to find the captured guy and at a later part was able to communicate to him through his mind. Our heroine encourages the guy to hold on until he can be rescued and has been asking him for any kind of clue that could help them locate him faster, like if he can hear anything from his surroundings or smell anything, etc. The woman's voice in his head became the only light in his darkened state, seeing as he is imprisoned in some dark tight place. The guy was rescued eventually in the middle of the book and finally got to see the woman he had been talking to and they became close and started a relationship but of course his captor remains looming over their head. I tried *The Third Eye* by Lois Duncan, Maya Banks's  *Whispers in the Dark*, and *The Keeper* by T.F. Allen, but none of them match what I am looking for. Anyone know the title and author of the book?