# Romantic sci-fi suspense young adult book about a guy held in captivity and a girl who can see other people's memories

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

Around the early 1990s, I read this book about a guy held in captivity and a girl working with fbi or something. She can see memories of the person by touching an object, and maybe she's telepathic as well. She was able to connect to the guy who was missing.

All I remember is that the guy was in some sort of coffin, and during his times of captivity, the voice of the girl in his head gave him hope. I tried Maya Bank's *Whispers in the Dark*, but the story doesn't match. Anyone know?

Comment: This sounds something like one of Niven's *Gil the ARM* stories; Gil trapped but checked in on by the staff telepath happens at least once, but I need to find the book to figure out which.  At a guess it might be "Death by Ecstacy."

Comment: Tried that book but within a couple of pages I just know it isn't. Nice book though so I'm gonna finish it later.

Comment: This is probably the same story as [Fiction Romance. Heroine uses her psychic ability such as telepathy and psychometry to help find a man who's been kidnapped](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/238730/fiction-romance-heroine-uses-her-psychic-ability-such-as-telepathy-and-psychome), though that question has no answers.